# For a 5'X9'balcony up 12-18 ft I need a good short antenna for 40m USB. Openings ~5x 8 ft to west 5'X4ft to south w/3' metal balustrades

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction

Is there a 2-3 meter long loaded dipole for the USB 40m ham band that I can use on a 2nd floor balcony?

Comment: If you can’t project a (more than 4M) long fishing rod out of your balcony, but have to stay within the balcony, my guess is that a small magnetic loop antenna might be more efficient than a 2 or 3 meter long dipole on 40M.  You’ll have to experiment.

Comment: Thanks, hotpaw2 - An easily-stored away fishing pole or even a Hustler is the probably a good way to go - maybe coupling the two balustrades as a working 'ground.'

Comment: Would you please make that an answer @hotpaw2?